# Sitecore website as a subsite of an existing non-Sitecore website

Tags: iis, sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

We have two websites:

1. the first one is a non-Sitecore website (e.g.
   *www.non-sitecore-site.com*)
2. the second one is a Sitecore website (e.g. *www.sitecore-site.com*)

My task is to make the second one (Sitecore-based website) as a subsite of the first website, which is accessible via *www.non-sitecore-site.com/sitecore-site*.

I tried to make a virtual folder in IIS, convert it to a web application and set it up for the Sitecore-based site folder. However it does not work, even if I configure `virtualFolder` and `physicalFolder` both equal to *"/sitecore-site*" in Sitecore config files.

Is it actually feasible?
Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sitecore resolves a site via a pipeline process within the `httpRequestBegin` pipeline. The `SiteResolver` sets a context site based on the following criteria:

- Hostname
- Virtual path
- Port number

Sitecore processes the config XML in sequence to find the first site matching the above criteria. Since each site has a `hostName` attribute defined, Sitecore first checks against the `hostName` then the `virtualFolder` which by default is simply “/”. So, the first thing for you is to review a sequence of your site definitions to make sure that more specific configurations are placed on top and more generic ones - at the bottom.

To configure a Sitecore site as a virtual folder simply set the `virtualFolder` and `physicalFolder` attributes to the same value to match your expected path *'/sitecore-site'*, i.e. your site configuration will look like:

```
<site name="yoursite" hostName="www.non-sitecore-site.com" virtualFolder="/sitecore-site" physicalFolder="/sitecore-site" ...
```

You don’t need to create neither a physical folder *'sitecore-sit'* nor a virtual folder *'sitecore-sit'* in IIS pointing to your Sitecore site.

Comment: How then this should be configured in IIS? I already have a binding for www.non-sitecore-site.com which is bound to non-Sitecore based website and has nothing to do with Sitecore. If I add the same one for Sitecore it will not work. How the request will reach Sitecore then?

Comment: You should configure your Sitecore website in IIS as a dedicated instance and point its physical path to your Sitecore folder in the file system. Ideally, you should configure a proxy site in addition to your existing two and assign the main `www.non-sitecore-site.com` host name to it only, then setup proxy rewriting rules within it to reroute the web traffic accordingly between non-Sitecore and Sitecore sites based on the requested URL. If you share the same hosting space then you can use local IPs and ports for proxy redirects between different sites.